# laravel Undefined offset: 1 callback function

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am using https://github.com/Chumper/Datatable for datatables. It has worked well but it seems that although I did not really change anything. It stopped working. There was also no update to any packages from when it was working to when it was not. I do not think it is any problem with the library itself, most likely something basic I am missing here.

Anyway what is happening is I am creating a column, the return value is part of an array coming from one column in the database. The reason for this is the data changes often, so the columns are combined into one column (uses elasticsearch for the actual search)

```
if(Datatable::shouldHandle())
{
    $data = Item::select('id', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'cat_id', 'quick_access')->where('cat_id', '=', $id)->get();

    return Datatable::collection($data)
        ->addColumn('unit_id', function($model){
            return HTML::linkRoute('inventory.items.show', $model->quick_access[0], [$model->cat_id, $model->id]);
        })
        ->addColumn('column1', function($model){
            return $model->quick_access[1];
        })
        ->addColumn('column2', function($model){
            return $model->quick_access[2];
        })
        ->addColumn('column3', function($model){
            return $model->quick_access[3];
        })
        ->addColumn('column4', function($model){
            return $model->quick_access[4];
        })
        ->addColumn('column5', function($model){
            return $model->quick_access[5];
        })
        ->addcolumn('created_at', function($model){
            return Carbon::parse($model->created_at)->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
        })
        ->addColumn('updated_at', function($model){
            return Carbon::parse($model->updated_at)->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
        })
        ->addColumn('id', function($model){
            return $model->id;
        })
        ->searchColumns('unit_id','column1','column2','column3','column4','column5')
        ->orderColumns('unit_id','column2','column4','column5','id')
        ->make();
}
```

Here is the problematic section, the second add column `column1` is where the error happens, it says `Undefined offset: 1` However testing it extensively the variable is fine. `$model->quick_access` is an array, as it should be and `$model->quick_access[1]` is a string, as it should be. However although it is correct, it triggers an error. This exact code worked fine before, just seemingly stopped.

Just in case there is any curiousity on how `quick_access` is an array, this is the part of the Model that handles it.

```
public function getQuickAccessAttribute($quick_access)
{
    return explode(';',$quick_access);
}
```

Anyway I am just running out of ideas for what this could be, has anyone ran across a similar issue before? where although you can dump the variable correctly, php says it does not exist?

Comment: Is the variable fine for every model in the collection? (Often with such things you forget that the error might just be one model in the collection...)

Comment: True, although the database does not show any missing it.... though your right one of those things I missed (brain dead today ><)

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being that a couple of the records had malformed. It was more of a domino effect that led to it, seemingly unrelated things coming together to cause it.

First in the database everything seemed alright. However there was an error where whenever an edit was made it was sent to store rather then update. Also the quick access feature was not added to store yet, leaving an empty array that did not appear in the same group as the rest (seeded data).

These 2 row's caused the issue, but being the last ones to go it was hard to isolate. The simplest fix was to use an if statement to diagnose when it happened. Once it was diagnosed and the new ID's could be found they could be removed, fixing the error.

lukasgeiter comment helped me finally diagnose this, one of those small stupid mistakes that leads to frustration.